# Restoring values to tokeninput field - jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery-tokeninput

I'm trying to take values from a `tokeninput` field, save them to localstorage then retrieve them later. I am getting an error. Code:

```
//Save to storage
 var selectedValues = $('#Contacts').tokenInput("get");
console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedValues));
localStorage.setItem('ContactsJSON', JSON.stringify(selectedValues));

//Restore
var names = localStorage.getItem("ContactsJSON");
console.log(names);
$.each(names, function (index, value) {
    $("#Contacts").tokenInput("add", value);
});
```

Error message is:

> Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

Error is showing at jquery-1.10.2.js (1009,2)

I'm quite sure that my JSON is correct, as per the [tokeninput docs](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/), it should be in the right format when retrieved using the get API:

`selector.tokenInput("get");
    Gets the array of selected tokens from the tokeninput (each item being an object of the kind {id: x, name: y}).`

The data I can see in localstorage is as follows:

`[{id":59,"name":"Steve Carrell"},{"id":58,"name":"John Krasinski"},{"id":1,"name":"Jenna Fischer"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you are getting string, not an object.

You should call `JSON.pase()` on your string from localstorage.

So, fixed code should look like:

```
// here you are converting object to string:
localStorage.setItem('ContactsJSON', JSON.stringify(selectedValues));

var names = localStorage.getItem("ContactsJSON");
// here you should convert string back to object
var names_object = JSON.parse(names);
console.log(names_object);
$.each(names_object, function (index, value) {
    $("#Contacts").tokenInput("add", value);
});
```

Comment: That worked! I had actually tried `JSON.parse` but I may have had a slightly different syntax (used a foreach rather than $.each). Thanks!